# Best practice for rails docker-compose db:create db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have simple rails application with `docker-compose.yml` file.
It consists from two containers - db container with PostgreSQL and web container with rails app.

In dockerfile for web part I have such lines in `CMD`

```
CMD RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:migrate && \
    bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0' --environment=production
```

So in line rake db:create db:migrate I create db if it is a first run of db container, and run migrate.

But if it is only update of web part - I need only to run db:migrate, and db:create (as it should) give me error

```
ERROR:  database "myapp_production" already exists
STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "myapp_production" ENCODING = 'unicode'
```

Everything working fine, but I think there is a better way.
What is a best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same development stack and here is that I'm doing.

Here is a Dockerfile for postgres which I'm extend:

```
FROM postgres:9.4

ADD db/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

From the [`docker postgres`](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) documentation:

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived
>   from this one, add one or more `*.sql` or `*.sh` scripts under
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (creating the directory if necessary).
>   After the entrypoint calls `initdb` to create the default postgres user
>   and database, it will run any `*.sql` files and source any `*.sh` scripts
>   found in that directory to do further initialization before starting
>   the service.

My `init.sql`:

```
CREATE USER database_user;
CREATE DATABASE database_production;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_production TO database_user;
```

After that my `RUN` command in the `web` container points to the `run.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Bundling gems"
bundle install --jobs 8 --retry 3

echo "Clearing logs"
bin/rake log:clear

echo "Run migrations"
bundle exec rake db:migrate

echo "Seed database"
bundle exec rake db:seed

echo "Removing contents of tmp dirs"
bin/rake tmp:clear

echo "Starting app server ..."
bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

That's it. My database created in the `db` container, and `web` app only does migration.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, my only idea was to perform some kind of `db:create` on db container creation level, not on web level.